# Determine Bitrate for WebM Video Files

Tags: video, webm

I am trying to debug some WebM videos and need to determine their bitrate. An application like FFmpeg can get this data but I have not been able to successfully install it on my system. Tools like Quicktime Player have "inspector" functionalities but, e.g., QT Player can't open WebM files.

Appreciate any suggestions people may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mediainfo is your friend: http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download
free and has GUI and CLI support.
hope this helps